# "At hand" vs "on hand" vs "in hand"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in, in-on

What's the difference between *at hand*, *on hand* and *in hand*? *At hand* seems to me as if you have something in reach. *On hand* is if you have something in stock. And *in hand* can be used as if you have more time at your disposal.

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way these different prepositions are used is all very much idiomatic, so there will be a limit to how far you can "rationalise" why any particular preposition is associated with any particular meaning. Especially in respect of "hand", since most of us always have a couple of those about our person ready to be incorporated into our word choices.

One thing I would say that "in" usually denotes something closer than "on" (which itself is usually closer than "at"), which is why the "nearby" meanings use the latter two.

Note that "in hand" doesn't actually mean *having more time at your disposal* - it's just that we often say we have *"time in hand"* (things *in hand* can be *in reserve, spare*). Apart from the literal *held in the hand*, the other common idiomatic usage for this one is that if something is *"in hand"* it's being actively dealt with (by implication, *really* close to you), not just sitting on your "to-do" list.

OP doesn't mention **to hand**, which is actually [more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20at%20hand,have%20on%20hand,have%20to%20hand&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) than the others in British English (but seemingly quite rare for Americans). In practice few would choose *at hand* or *on hand* on the basis of how physically close/accessible something was - largely pointless anyway, since few others would apprehend any subtle distinction being made. Go British and make life easier for everyone!

Comment: "In hand" is also, I think, the only one of the three that's used literally (as in, *pen in hand, ...*).

Comment: @onomatomaniak: I guess that depends how you define "literally" in the case of *"at"*, but I certainly think you're right about *"on"*. I can't think of any "literal" usage for that one. *"He's got* **LOVE** and **HATE** *tatoos on hand"*? Hmm - I don't think so!

Comment: ...just for the hell of it - *Q. "Have they engraved my writing set yet?" A. "They did the pencil and ballpoint yesterday, and they have the pen in hand today"*.

Comment: _In_ means _contained_, and that refers to one's physical hand, which is for containing things, among other uses. So all the uses of _in hand_ are metaphorical extensions of a grasping hand with something (like a tool, for instance) in it.

Comment: _At_ refers to "x,y" location on a plane, so _at hand_ means located at (though not necessarily _in_) one's hand. Anything _at hand_ is, well, _handy_.

Comment: _On_ normally refers to location on some 2-D plane in a 3-D space; movement away from the plane is _off_. Gravity may be assumed, so such movement is normally _up_. So something that is _on hand_ is located on some surface  (the word _shelf_ springs to mind) close enough to one's hand for it to be relevant -- if the shelf is in Singapore and I'm in Vancouver, I don't have it _on hand_.

Comment: Everything else is metaphor.

Comment: @John Lawler: Off-hand (so to speak!), I think maybe the way you lay it out gives something of the lie to my first sentence in the answer. I thought many of these various idiomatic usages were relatively arbitrary, but looked at from the right perspective they're actually pretty "accurate".

Comment: Um, s.e is asking me to avoid extended discussions in comments. Which is good, because I have lots of lectures about metaphor and the human body image it's mostly based on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2231/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-john-lawler)

Comment: BBC describes it a little differently. http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/askaboutenglish/2009/03/090324_aae_hand_page.shtml

Comment: @Mohammad: I can't see any conflict between what I wrote and what the BBC's "rent-a-pundit" says. He does seem more tolerant of *at hand* than I would be, but my answer doesn't mention my dislike of that variant in many contexts. Other than that he mentions *to hand* - which I didn't because OP didn't ask about that. But maybe I'll add it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If I am looking for my Credit Card, should I say: I don't have it in hand or at hand or on hand right now.

Comment: @Mohammad: I think nearly all Brits would say "to hand" regardless of the exact situation. Hardly anyone (even Americans) would say "in hand". But suppose you were on the phone at the time and you were being asked to read out the "security number" on the back of your card. I think some Americans might say "at" or "on" depending on whether they meant "but hang on a minute and I'll fetch it from my coat", as opposed to "I'll have to call again when I get home where my card is". But I don't know which way round, and I think that distinction is silly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks, I will go with to hand. I don't have my card to hand right now, but I can look it up for you. Right?

Comment: I gather that, when referring to the subject or situation being considered, "the matter in hand" is more correct than "the matter at hand"...

Answer (score 16):

At hand frequently refers to proximity in time, the other two usually relate to spatial proximity:

With the apocalypse at hand, I was pleased to find I have a cache of food and water on hand, and a rifle in hand.

Comment: I'd never seen (at least, never noticed) "at hand" used for that "imminent" sense before, but checking Google Books for [war at hand](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22war+at+hand%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) shows you're quite right. Primarily American usage, I guess. +1 for that, and for managing to get all three prepositions in one sentence. I read the last one as *rifle in reserve, spare*, rather than actually being held, but I suppose it's just ambiguous.

Comment: American English uses 'at hand' in that sense a lot.  "The time is at hand" is another common instance.

Answer (score 5):

Think of measures of distance:

in hand - literally within one's grasp - not even inches away - "A bird in the hand"

at hand - nearby - a few feet away at most - "He kept his cigarettes at hand"

on hand - somewhere accessible but fairly distant - more than a few feet away and less than a few hundred yards - "We have more vacuum cleaners on hand"

Answer (score 3):

I tried to break down the usage of these three (four if you count "to hand"), hopefully I'm right about it, at least in part :) So here are my thoughts:

- *In hand* mainly focuses on abstract things or uncountable things, it can be *a situation in hand*, *an hour in hand*, *some money in hand*, *a topic in hand* etc... (compare with "in question": *the man in question is guilty of ~ the topic in hand is a delicate one*).

Examples: 1) Pupils have over half an hour in hand = left/available/to spare. 2) We had our kitchen redone and still have some savings in hand = still left (didn't spend all of them). 3) The troops entered the village to take the situation in hand = to take it under control/to reign it in. 4) The matter in hand should be smoothed over with senior managers = the matter that is now being settled/the present issue that worries somebody.

- *At hand* can refer to time or distance (in close proximity). You can say that *retaliation is at hand*, *help was at hand*, *keep your tools close at hand* (here it's the same as *to hand*: Sadly, I don't have my wallet to hand) etc...

Examples: 1) The businessman was afraid that retaliation was at hand = would befall him soon/would soon follow. 2) The stranded group of tourists knew that help was at hand = a rescue operation to save them was commenced, and the rescue team would soon get the tourists off the island, they knew that =). 3) You might want to have a pen close at hand/to hand = have it nearby, somewhere close by so that it is easily accessible if you need it right away.

- With *on hand*, distance is not always the case, it's rather a matter of (a) availability and (b) something imminent about to happen: services were on hand, I'm always on hand, cash on hand.

Examples: 1) The emergency services were on hand with medical advice = they were available/they could be reached (over the phone, for instance) for some important medical advice. 2) He's often on hand to help you out = feel free to ask him if you're puzzled about something/he can often be of help if you ask him about something. 3) The company needs to have cash on hand = it has to have cash available for some purposes, the cash should be easily accessed, so to speak. 4) Are there enough people on hand to get started? = are there enough people present (maybe they are members of some committee or board) to hold a meeting? 5) A change was on hand (=at hand) = it was imminent/about to happen soon.

While there are rules there is also common usage, it's worth remembering that these prepositions can occaionally be interchangeable. It's advisable to refer to dictionaries and pay attention to the way native speakers use these prepositions, TV shows can come in handy for that matter as well. =)