# Which is better equivalent for “in stock”? “At hand”, “on hand”, or “in hand”?

Tags: word-choice, prepositional-phrases, in-on, at-on

Which is a better equivalent for “in stock” (meaning a product is in stock)?

- “at hand”
- “on hand”
- “in hand”

Can any of them be used? Which is the most appropriate? Which is second-best?

Comment: In stock:
available for sale or use; on hand.

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55040/at-hand-vs-on-hand-vs-in-hand

Comment: "at hand" means "easily available" and could just as easily refer to an inanimate object or a person.

"on hand" means "in our inventory", so it's probably closest to "in stock".

"in hand" means "I'm literally holding the object right now."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

> On hand

Followed by:

> In hand.

I have never heard this and it doesn't sound correct at all:

> At hand.

Comment: **At Hand** is fine....it is for an item that is within current reach, such as your coffee cup or pen at your desk.

Comment: @Oldcat possibly, but I have never heard it in context of products being in stock and it doesn't sound right in that case to me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe *on hand* is probably the best phrase to use synonymical to *in stock*.
Edit: In response to a question about my reason, it simply seems to sound most fluent in the context, although the other ways of phrasing would also be grammatically valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say they're mostly interchangeable, however there are occasions when I would use one over the other:

"I kept my sword close at hand"

"I remain on hand to help you

"I keep a good deal of cash in hand"

I would use either "on hand" or "in hand" - "The stock I keep on hand is shown on the accounts as "Stock in hand"".

Answer (score 0):

While studying Financial accounting, I remember always using these terms:

- *Stock-in-hand* for Stock balance.
- *Cash-in-hand* for Cash balance.
- *Cash-at-Bank* for Bank balance.