# Replace "in possession" with in / at / on hand?

Tags: prepositions

[Another related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55040/at-hand-vs-on-hand-vs-in-hand) but I have not found a clear answer over there. Which one is closer in meaning to "in possession" of an object? This doesn't have to mean physically in hand or physically close, but the requirement is just you own it aka the fact that you have or own an object aka in possession. For example: The condition will not be met unless you still have the item "in possession" (which one "in / at / on / to hand" can replace this?)

Tis not a very clear example, but it is similar to the sentence I'm currently facing. Note that I would like to know both the BE and AmE version of the answer if there are differences.

Comment: None of the expressions "in / at / on / to hand" reflect the meaning of "in possession". Your example can be corrected by omitting "in possession" -- "Possession" describes *the state of having control (and/or certain rights) over something*. It ***sometimes*** implies ownership but not always. --The verb "to have" also performs this function in its main meaning.

Comment: 'In possession' is rarely used this way. And you may possess an object, but it might not be readily on hand. 'On hand' means 'readily available for use', and 'at hand' and 'to hand' are less common synonyms. 'In hand' usually means 'still unused'. But where is your research? Dictionaries provide helpful example sentences.

Comment: I already "searched". Most of it has been discussed in the site, see attached link. But still, I don't know, why is it that I feel like it could somehow in someway be replaced with one of those? Instinctively speaking. Is it really true that none of those communicates "possession" in someway? It might just be my asumption though

Comment: @greybeard. If i wanted to emphasize the fact that you should still own it, should I omit "in possession" in the above phrase? What should I replace it with in order to emphasize it correctly?